# Error 403 forbidden - using HttpURLConnection - authorization issue?

Tags: android, json, httpurlconnection

I have responseCode = 403.

Do you see any issue in the code below?

I tried every flag in the Base64.encode.

My site woks perfectly fine: once I login in manually from http passing my username/passwd, I'm able to retrieve the JSON data using https.

Do you think I'm correct in suspecting an authorization issue?

```
        URL object = new URL("https://aaaaaa.bb/api/?format=json" );

        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) object.openConnection();

        connection.setReadTimeout(60 * 1000);
        connection.setConnectTimeout(60 * 1000);
        connection.setRequestMethod("GET");

        String authorization="xxxxxx@gmail.com:yyyyyy";
        String encodedAuth="Basic "+ Base64.encode(authorization.getBytes(), Base64.DEFAULT);
        connection.setRequestProperty("Authorization", encodedAuth);

        connection.connect();
        int responseCode = connection.getResponseCode();
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try by setting the content type:

```
connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
```

Comment: in my case it would be: connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json") right?

Comment: Ohh sorry it would be "application/json".